# An unexpected strcpy segfault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I've discovered a segfault that I'm having trouble parsing. Lest you think I haven't searched, I don't *think* the issue is the same as in [this question](http://typedef%20struct%20usage%20usage;%20struct%20usage%7B%20%09char%20name[9];%20//variable%20name%20%09int%20loc;%20//location%20in%20use%20list.%20%20%09usage%20*next;%20%7D;). I have the following typedef'd structure:

```
typedef struct usage usage;
struct usage{
      char name[9]; 
      int loc;  
      usage *next;
};
```

I'm reading data from a file that consists of a number K followed by K pairs (S,D) where S= an 8-character string [this is a variable name] and d= an integer [a memory location].

Here's the code that's causing the error:

```
void addUse(int index,char *nm, int addr){
     usage *temp;
     strcpy(temp->name,nm); //segfault here. 
     temp->loc = addr;
     temp->next= NULL;
    /* more processing */
}
```

To make this clearer, I am calling this function from a block where I have

```
int dummyIndex = 1;
char s1[9];
int val1; 
scanf(" %s %d, s1, &val1);
addUse(dummyIndex, s1, val1);
```

It seems like in the question I linked to the issue is that they do not allocation the `char` on the heap. I am not sure what's happening here. Using identical calls to `strcpy` on another `struct` with a field `char name[9]` works just fine.

What am I missing? What have I over looked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to initialize the temp pointer, so it's pointing to random memory. When you then write

```
strcpy(temp->name, mm);
```

You're following a pointer to a random address and writing bytes there, hence the segfault.

Comment: hey! thanks! i saw you posted your answer as I was typing my solution. staring at code for days can create silly errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line of your code

```
usage *temp;
strcpy(temp->name,nm); //segfault here.
```

You are not initializing the `temp` pointer so it is taking a garbage value.

Try initializing it before `strcpy`

```
usage *temp = malloc(sizeof(usage));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no `new` in `C`, you mean `malloc(sizeof *temp);` ;)

Comment: Oh, I thought it is C++. You are right. I mean malloc.

Comment: @AlterMann I am sure (and tested), you cannot assign void* to usage*. So it is mandatory to type cast it like this. usage* temp = (usage*) malloc(sizeof(usage));

Comment: @AlterMann please edit the answer, otherwise it makes the answer incorrect.

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler? you should [not cast the result of `malloc` in `C`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my issue:

in other calls I make sure to set `temp = malloc(sizeof(struct));` not in this one so I'm trying to write to memory that hasn't been allocated!.

Comment: Also better to use `%8s` instead of `%s` in `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is clear, and the `SegFault` happens in the exact location where it should. The reason is that you are using memory you haven't previously allocated.

```
void addUse(int index,char *nm, int addr){
     usage *temp;
     strcpy(temp->name,nm); //segfault here. 
     // ...
}
```

When you declare "**usage** *temp;" you're creating a pointer *temp* of type **usage**. Terrific. But... where is the pointer pointing to? You don't know. The value of *temp*, the memory address it contains is the garbage that happens to be in the place it occupies in memory when it is created (other programming languages give a default value to uninitialized variables, but C is not in that group).

So... you're being lucky. Your program is best described as "[undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)", since it is possible that temp contains a memory address that casually is unoccupied: your program could run pass this function, crash elsewhere, and you would not have a clue about why.

Another problem is that you should return the new **struct** usage, while your function is returning `void`.

This is the function as it should be:

```
usage * addUse(int index,char *nm, int addr){
     usage *temp = malloc(sizeof(usage));

     if ( temp == NULL) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     strcpy(temp->name,nm); //segfault here. 
     temp->loc = addr;
     temp->next= NULL;
    /* more processing */

     return temp;
}
```

I understand that you should link the pointer returned by *addUse()* to a linked list.

Hope this helps.